# How to update UI using the JSON result through a completion handler?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to update some labels based on data returned from JSON. Here are the data objects and the function to update the JSON data objects :

```
class sampleJSON {


  var airbnbUS: Int?
  var airbnbLocal: Int?


  init(airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int?) {
    self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
    self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal
  }

  //Used to download data to local objects using the network service manager
  static func downloadAllData(urlExtension: String, completionHandler: @escaping (sampleJSON?) -> ()) {

    let usm = UrlSessionNetworkManager.sharedManager

    if let jsonDictionary = usm.parseJSONFromData(urlExtension:"\(urlExtension)")

    {
      if let resultsDictionary = jsonDictionary["result"] as? [[String : Any]]?{
        let costDictionary = resultsDictionary?[0]
        let cost = costDictionary?["cost"] as? [String: Any]

        if let airbnb = cost?["airbnb_median"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let airbnbUS = airbnb["USD"] as! Int
            let airbnbLocal = airbnb["CHF"] as! Int

         sampleJSON(airbnbUS: airbnbUS, airbnbLocal: airbnbLocal)
        }
      }
    } else {
      print("Error: Cannot retrieve JSON Data")
    }
  }
}
```

Here is where I'm trying to update UI:

```
var JSON: sampleJSON?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       sampleJSON.downloadAllData(urlExtension:"cities/basel-switzerland",completionHandler: {_ in

  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
  self.topLabel.text = String(describing: self.JSON?.airbnbUS)
  self.lowerLabel.text = String(describing: self.JSON?.airbnbLocal)
   })
})
```

As of right now when the viewDidload is called the labels are blank, I tried adding a  `self.view.setNeedsDisplay()` to the end of the completion block but the labels still remain blank.
 EDIT: I noticed if I put a breakpoint inside the completion block in the viewDidLoad it's not called.

Comment: did you try updating the labels on the main queue? Using: `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {   })`

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never call your completion handler within `downloadAllData` so its closure will never execute to set your labels.

In place of this line where you create a `sampleJSON` and do nothing with it:

```
sampleJSON(airbnbUS: airbnbUS, airbnbLocal: airbnbLocal)
```

return `sampleJSON` within `completionHandler`:

```
completionHandler(sampleJSON(airbnbUS: airbnbUS, airbnbLocal: airbnbLocal))
```

Comment: This makes sense but now the labels return nil

Comment: @SwiftyJD That's because your completion block should be using the returned `sampleJSON` as `downloadAllData`'s completion handler indicates, but you're ignoring those values by replacing them with _.  Instead of using those return values you're using `self.JSON?.airbnbUS` and `self.JSON?.airbnbLocal` when it seems as if `self.JSON` hasn't been set at any point in your code and thus equals nil. If `self.JSON == nil`, `self.JSON?.airbnbUS` and `self.JSON?.airbnbLocal` will also equal nil. So in short, use the `sampleJSON` returned from `downloadAllData` to populate your labels.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. It works now, thanks for your help!